# Generic method in java

Tags: java

```
public class Stack<T> {
  public <T> T pop() throws Exception;
}
```

Why do I need `<T>` in  method `public <T> T pop() throws Exception`?

Comment: You shouldn't need the <T> here.  Is there a particular error you're getting if you don't?

Comment: You'll only need `<T>` for `static` methods

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to put  there `public T pop() throws Exception` works fine.

More detailed explanation is available here http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genmethods.html

It seems just a convention and preference, Java infers the Type even if you do not provide the type in the method.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a warning that your method's generic type parameter `T` is hiding the generic type `T` of the class. Check out the `java.util.Stack` class. It does it differently

```
public
class Stack<E> extends Vector<E> {
   // ...
   public synchronized E pop() {
   // ...
```